# error CS0411:The type arguments for method `UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectOfType<T>()'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**This is the full error:**

> Assets/Scripts/BoxLauncher.cs(15,32): error CS0411: The type arguments
>   for method `UnityEngine.Object.FindObjectOfType()' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

**This is my code:**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class BoxLauncher : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] boxPrefabs;

    public float fireDelay = 3f;
    public float nextFire = 1f;

    public float fireVelocity = 10f;

    void FixedUpdate () {


        // This is the line that the error is pointing to.
        if (GameObject.FindObjectOfType().hasLost){
            return;
        }

        nextFire -= Time.deltaTime;

        if(nextFire <= 0) {
            // Spawn a new box!
            nextFire = fireDelay;

            GameObject boxGO = (GameObject)Instantiate( 
                        boxPrefabs[ Random.Range(0, boxPrefabs.Length)], 
                        transform.position,
                        transform.rotation
                        );

            boxGO.rigidbody2D.velocity = transform.rotation * new Vector2(0, fireVelocity);

            GameObject.FindObjectOfType<ScoreManager>().score++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GameObject.FindObjectOfType() requires an object type to find. You didn't define and object type?   Try adding a type such as GUItexture.

The code would look like:
`GameObject.FindObjectOfType(typeof(GUITexture))`
instead of : `GameObject.FindObjectOfType();`